# Custom Mapping With Automapper Using Global.asax

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a static mapper class that is called from the Global.asax that can map simple classes fine:

Global.asax:

```
AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

AutoMapperConfiguration:

```
Configure()
{
  Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<TMS.Entity.CourseSession, DataAccess.Entities.CourseSession>(); });
  Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<TMS.Entity.Course, DataAccess.Entities.Course>()
```

where `CourseSession` is a nested object in `Course`

```
public class Course 
{
  public ICollection<CourseSession> CourseSessionColl;
```

No matter what is seem to do in the mapper it throws an error:

> The following property on DataAccess.Entities.CourseSession cannot be mapped: 
>       CourseSessionColl

It works if I ignore the property:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<TMS.Entity.Course, DataAccess.Entities.Course>()
            .ForMember(o => o.CourseSessionColl, s => s.Ignore())
```

but if I try to map it it always throws an error.

***Edit - Added example of classes***

The property in the classes in named the same and also I have the mapping for these preceding that of this map:

```
namespace TMS.Entity
{
  public class Course
  {
    public ICollection<CourseSession> CourseSessionColl { get; set; }
    ...

------------------------------------------------

namespace DataAccess.Entities
{
  public class Course
  {
    public ICollection<CourseSession> CourseSessionColl { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you have in your both classes the property `CourseSessionColl` with the same name?

Comment: Yep. Just added an edit with examples of the classes. The course session isn't the same class but they are identical and already mapped prior to this mapping taking place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `Initialize` method twice and the second call overrides the first configuration. You will need to add more maps in the same configuration instead of calling multiple times the `Initialize` method:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { 
cfg.CreateMap<TMS.Entity.CourseSession, DataAccess.Entities.CourseSession>();
cfg.CreateMap<TMS.Entity.Course, DataAccess.Entities.Course>(); });
```